# Hibernate performance issue with updates more than 10K records

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

I am presently trying to do a bulk upload operation where in i need to parse an excel and update the details into the database. The problem is the data needs to be stored into multiple tables and the relationship is maintained. The problem is not when i have about 50-100 records to updated, but hugely affected when i have around 50000 records to be updated. It takes ages to upload and sometimes the browser gives up waiting for the response to arrive. Please find below the code and the mapping files. Please let me know what i can do to increase the performance and complete the processing quicker.

**Note:** The cascades are all required.

```
***.hbm.xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Mar 19, 2012 9:24:47 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.3.0.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.****.****.hibernate.****" table="V_ACCOUNT_DIM">
        <id name="acctDimIdN" type="long">
            <column name="ACCT_DIM_ID_N" precision="10" scale="0" />
             <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">ACCOUNT_DIM_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="gdwIdN" type="long">
            <column name="GDW_ID_N" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="pycisInstnIdN" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="PYCIS_INSTN_ID_N" precision="10" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="acctNotesC" type="string">
            <column name="ACCT_NOTES_C" length="4000" />
        </property>
        <property name="trdSysShrtNmC" type="string">
            <column name="TRD_SYS_SHRT_NM_C" length="100" />
        </property>
        <property name="reimbAuthorizeD" type="date">
            <column name="REIMB_AUTHORIZE_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="reimbInitD" type="date">
            <column name="REIMB_INIT_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="reimbEffD" type="date">
            <column name="REIMB_EFF_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="acctGainLossAmtN" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="ACCT_GAIN_LOSS_AMT_N" precision="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="buySellIndC" type="string">
            <column name="BUY_SELL_IND_C" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="navImpcN" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="NAV_IMPC_N" precision="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="delIndC" type="string">
            <column name="DEL_IND_C" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="updUsrC" type="string">
            <column name="UPD_USR_C" length="12" />
        </property>
        <property name="updTsD" type="date">
            <column name="UPD_TS_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="insUsrC" type="string">
            <column name="INS_USR_C" length="12" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="insTsD" type="date">
            <column name="INS_TS_D" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="incidentAcctSecFacts" table="V_INCIDENT_ACCT_SEC_FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="ACCT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.****.***.***.I***Fact" />
        </set>
        <set name="incidentAcctFacts" table="V_INCIDENT_ACCT_FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="ACCT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.****.***.***.I***Fact" />
        </set>
        <set name="accountAttachmentFacts" table="V_ACCOUNT_ATTACHMENT_FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="ACCT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.****.***.***.A****Fact" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

I****Dim.hbm.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Mar 19, 2012 9:24:47 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.3.0.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.****.***.***.I****Dim" table="V_****_DIM">
        <id name="incidentDimIdN" type="long">
            <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="10" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">INCIDENT_DIM_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="errMemoIdC" type="string">
            <column name="ERR_MEMO_ID_C" length="60" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="errMemoD" type="date">
            <column name="ERR_MEMO_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="idD" type="date">
            <column name="ID_D" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="incidentD" type="date">
            <column name="INCIDENT_D" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="ntfcD" type="date">
            <column name="NTFC_D" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="totGainLossN" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="TOT_GAIN_LOSS_N" precision="18"  scale="2"/>
        </property>
        <property name="ovrdAttachedAcctC" type="string">
            <column name="OVRD_ATTACHED_ACCT_C" length="1" />
        </property>
        <property name="gainLossCalcMthdC" type="string">
            <column name="GAIN_LOSS_CALC_MTHD_C" length="4000" />
        </property>
        <property name="deemedAnErrC" type="string">
            <column name="DEEMED_AN_ERR_C" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="errRatifiedC" type="string">
            <column name="ERR_RATIFIED_C" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="errAcctUsedC" type="string">
            <column name="ERR_ACCT_USED_C" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="aprvPrcsC" type="string">
            <column name="APRV_PRCS_C" length="4000" />
        </property>
        <property name="incidentShrtDescC" type="string">
            <column name="INCIDENT_SHRT_DESC_C" length="4000" />
        </property>
        <property name="incidentSumC" type="string">
            <column name="INCIDENT_SUM_C" length="4000" />
        </property>
        <property name="incidentNotesC" type="string">
            <column name="INCIDENT_NOTES_C" length="4000" />
        </property>
        <property name="delIndC" type="string">
            <column name="DEL_IND_C" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="updUsrC" type="string">
            <column name="UPD_USR_C" length="12" />
        </property>
        <property name="updTsD" type="date">
            <column name="UPD_TS_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="insUsrC" type="string">
            <column name="INS_USR_C" length="12" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="insTsD" type="date">
            <column name="INS_TS_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <set name="incidentAttachmentFacts" table="V_****FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="10" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.****.***.***.I***Fact" />
        </set>
        <set name="incidentActionItemFacts" table="V_****_FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.****.***.***.I****Fact" />
        </set>
        <set name="incidentAcctSecFacts" table="V_****FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.***.***.****.IncidentAcctSecFact" />
        </set>
        <set name="irgMemberAssignmentFacts" table="V_IRG_MEMBER_ASSIGNMENT_FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.***.***.****.IrgMemberAssignmentFact" />
        </set>
        <set name="incidentAcctFacts" table="V_INCIDENT_ACCT_FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.***.***.****.IncidentAcctFact" />
        </set>
        <set name="acctAttachmentFacts" table="V_ACCOUNT_ATTACHMENT_FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.***.***.****.AccountAttachmentFact" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

CerSecurityDim.hbm.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Mar 19, 2012 9:24:47 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.3.0.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.***.***.****.CerSecurityDim" table="V_CER_SECURITY_DIM">
        <id name="cerSecuDimIdN" type="long">
            <column name="CER_SECU_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" />
             <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">CER_SECURITY_DIM_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="fmrCusipC" type="string">
            <column name="FMR_CUSIP_C" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="tckrC" type="string">
            <column name="TCKR_C" length="30" />
        </property>
        <property name="secuNmC" type="string">
            <column name="SECU_NM_C" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="numOfShrTrdN" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="NUM_OF_SHR_TRD_N" precision="10" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="secuGainLossN" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="SECU_GAIN_LOSS_N" precision="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="buySellIndC" type="string">
            <column name="BUY_SELL_IND_C" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="delIndC" type="string">
            <column name="DEL_IND_C" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="updUsrC" type="string">
            <column name="UPD_USR_C" length="12" />
        </property>
        <property name="updTsD" type="date">
            <column name="UPD_TS_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="insUsrC" type="string">
            <column name="INS_USR_C" length="12" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="insTsD" type="date">
            <column name="INS_TS_D" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="incidentAcctSecFacts" table="V_INCIDENT_ACCT_SEC_FACT" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  >
            <key>
                <column name="SECU_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.***.***.****.IncidentAcctSecFact" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


IncidentAcctFact.hbm.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Mar 19, 2012 9:24:47 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.3.0.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.***.***.****.IncidentAcctFact" table="V_INCIDENT_ACCT_FACT">
        <id name="incidentAcctFactIdN" type="long">
            <column name="INCIDENT_ACCT_FACT_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">INCIDENT_ACCT_FACT_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="accountDim" class="com.***.***.****.AccountDim" fetch="select">
            <column name="ACCT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="incidentDim" class="com.***.***.****.IncidentDim" fetch="select">
            <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
       <!--  <many-to-one name="attachmentTypeDim" class="com.***.***.****.AttachmentTypeDim" fetch="select">
            <column name="ATTACHMENT_TYPE_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="false" />
        </many-to-one> -->
        <property name="relEffFromD" type="date">
            <column name="REL_EFF_FROM_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="relEffThruD" type="date">
            <column name="REL_EFF_THRU_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="ltstRelIndC" type="string">
            <column name="LTST_REL_IND_C" length="1" />
        </property>
        <property name="delIndC" type="string">
            <column name="DEL_IND_C" length="1" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="updUsrC" type="string">
            <column name="UPD_USR_C" length="12" />
        </property>
        <property name="updTsD" type="date">
            <column name="UPD_TS_D" length="7" />
        </property>
        <property name="insUsrC" type="string">
            <column name="INS_USR_C" length="12" />
        </property>
        <property name="insTsD" type="date">
            <column name="INS_TS_D" length="7" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


IncidentAcctSecFact.hbm.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Mar 19, 2012 9:24:47 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.3.0.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.***.***.****.IncidentAcctSecFact" table="V_INCIDENT_ACCT_SEC_FACT">
        <id name="incidentAcctSecIdN" type="long">
            <column name="INCIDENT_ACCT_SEC_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">INCIDENT_ACCT_SEC_FACT_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="accountDim" class="com.***.***.****.AccountDim" fetch="select">
        <column name="ACCT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="cerSecurityDim" class="com.***.***.****.CerSecurityDim" fetch="select">
            <column name="SECU_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="incidentDim" class="com.***.***.****.IncidentDim" fetch="select">
            <column name="INCIDENT_DIM_ID_N" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
         <property name="relEffFromD" type="date">
             <column name="REL_EFF_FROM_D" length="7" />
         </property>
         <property name="relEffThruD" type="date">
             <column name="REL_EFF_THRU_D" length="7" />
         </property>
         <property name="ltstRelIndC" type="string">
             <column name="LTST_REL_IND_C" length="1" />
         </property>
         <property name="delIndC" type="string">
             <column name="DEL_IND_C" length="1" />
         </property>
         <property name="updUsrC" type="string">
             <column name="UPD_USR_C" length="12" />
         </property>
         <property name="updTsD" type="date">
             <column name="UPD_TS_D" length="7" />
         </property>
         <property name="insUsrC" type="string">
             <column name="INS_USR_C" length="12" />
         </property>
         <property name="insTsD" type="date">
             <column name="INS_TS_D" length="7" />
         </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


The method where the actual processing is as follows.

   public boolean retrieveDataAndParseFile(IncidentDetailsForm incidentDetailsForm,  BaseViewBean baseViewBean$Session, 
                                                ActionMessages errors) throws Exception {
        boolean savedStatus = false;    
        boolean deletedstatus = false;

        /*List<AccountDim> accountsList = new ArrayList<AccountDim>();
        List<CerSecurityDim> cerSecuList = new ArrayList<CerSecurityDim>();
        List<IncidentAcctSecFact> inciAcctSecFactList = new ArrayList<IncidentAcctSecFact>();
        List<IncidentAcctFact> inciAcctFactList = new ArrayList<IncidentAcctFact>();
        List<IncidentDim> incidentList = new ArrayList<IncidentDim>();*/

        try {
            double totalSecGL= 0.00;
            double secTrdNetTotal= 0.00;
            DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

            String loginUser = baseViewBean$Session.getLoggedInUser().getUserId();
            List<Long> addedElementList = new ArrayList<Long>();

            CerSecurityDim cerSecDim = null;
            AccountDim account = null;
            IncidentAcctSecFact iasFact = null;
            IncidentAcctFact iaFact = null;
            long incidentId = baseViewBean$Session.getIncidentDim$Session().getIncidentDimIdN();
            IncidentDim incident = (IncidentDim)incidentDimDao.findById(IncidentDim.class, incidentId);
            ExcelListenerBean beanDetails;

            List<AccountDim> acctList = new ArrayList<AccountDim>();
            List <CerSecurityDim> cerSecList = new ArrayList<CerSecurityDim>();
            List <IncidentAcctSecFact> iasFactList = new ArrayList<IncidentAcctSecFact>();

            for (Map.Entry<Integer, ExcelListenerBean> entry : baseViewBean$Session.getExcelRecords().entrySet())
            {
                beanDetails = entry.getValue();

                //Initialize the net amounts for incorrect trade and correction trade.
                secTrdNetTotal= 0;

                cerSecDim = new CerSecurityDim();
                account = new AccountDim();
                iasFact = new IncidentAcctSecFact();
                iaFact = new IncidentAcctFact();

                //
                Object[] pycisDet = investmentDimDao.getPyCISIdByShrtName(beanDetails.getShortName());
                if(pycisDet != null && pycisDet.length > 0){
                    account.setPycisInstnIdN((Long)pycisDet[0]);
                    account.setGdwIdN((Long)pycisDet[1]);
                    account.setTrdSysShrtNmC(beanDetails.getShortName());
                    if(!addedElementList.contains((Long)pycisDet[0])){
                        addedElementList.add((Long)pycisDet[0]);
                    } 
                } 

                //
                cerSecDim.setFmrCusipC(beanDetails.getFmrCusip());
                SecurityDim sec = getSecDetailsByCusip(beanDetails.getFmrCusip());
                if(sec != null){
                    cerSecDim.setSecuNmC(sec.getSecuNmC());
                    cerSecDim.setTckrC(sec.getTckrC());
                }else {
                    cerSecDim.setSecuNmC("UNKNOWN");
                    cerSecDim.setTckrC("UNKNOWN");
                }

                //
                cerSecDim.setNumOfShrTrdN(beanDetails.getIncorrectTrdShares().longValue());

                //
                cerSecDim.setBuySellIndC(beanDetails.getIncorrectTrdBuySell().toUpperCase());
                account.setBuySellIndC(beanDetails.getIncorrectTrdBuySell().toUpperCase());

                //
                secTrdNetTotal  = Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(beanDetails.getIncorrectTrdNet())) +
                                                Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(beanDetails.getCorrectionTrdNet()));

                //
                totalSecGL = totalSecGL + secTrdNetTotal;

                boolean updatedStatus = false;

                // create the relationship and then add to the respective lists.
                cerSecDim.setInsUsrC(loginUser);
                cerSecDim.setInsTsD(AppGlobalUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp());
                cerSecDim.setDelIndC(AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.No);

                if(!acctList.isEmpty()){
                    for( AccountDim olderAccount :acctList){
                        if(olderAccount.getPycisInstnIdN().compareTo(account.getPycisInstnIdN()) == 0) {
                            double newAcctGainLossAmt=0;
                            double oldAcctGainLossAmt=0;
                            if(account.getAcctGainLossAmtN() != null){
                                newAcctGainLossAmt = account.getAcctGainLossAmtN();
                            }
                            if(olderAccount.getAcctGainLossAmtN() != null){
                                oldAcctGainLossAmt = olderAccount.getAcctGainLossAmtN();
                            }
                            double newGLAmt = newAcctGainLossAmt + oldAcctGainLossAmt;
                            account = olderAccount;
                            account.setAcctGainLossAmtN(newGLAmt);
                            updatedStatus = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(!cerSecList.isEmpty()){
                    for(CerSecurityDim olderCerSecDim : cerSecList){
                        if(olderCerSecDim.getFmrCusipC().equals(cerSecDim.getFmrCusipC())) {
                            cerSecDim = olderCerSecDim;
                            double newSecuGainLoss = 0;
                            double oldSecuGainLoss = 0;
                            if(cerSecDim.getSecuGainLossN() != null){
                                newSecuGainLoss = cerSecDim.getSecuGainLossN();
                            }
                            if(olderCerSecDim.getSecuGainLossN() != null){
                                oldSecuGainLoss = olderCerSecDim.getSecuGainLossN();
                            }
                            cerSecDim.setSecuGainLossN(newSecuGainLoss + oldSecuGainLoss);

                            for(IncidentAcctSecFact olderIASFact : iasFactList){
                                if(olderIASFact != null && olderIASFact.getCerSecurityDim() != null
                                        && olderIASFact.getCerSecurityDim().getFmrCusipC().equals(cerSecDim.getFmrCusipC())){
                                    iasFact = olderIASFact;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!deletedstatus){
                    deleteAllImpactedAccounts(baseViewBean$Session);
                    deletedstatus = true;
                }
                totalSecGL = Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(totalSecGL));

                account.setInsUsrC(loginUser);
                account.setInsTsD(AppGlobalUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp());
                account.setDelIndC(AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.No);
                accountDimDao.saveOrUpdate(account);

                iasFact.setAccountDim(account);
                iasFact.setIncidentDim(incident);
                iasFact.setCerSecurityDim(cerSecDim);
                iasFact.setInsUsrC(loginUser);
                iasFact.setInsTsD(AppGlobalUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp());
                iasFact.setDelIndC(AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.No);

                cerSecDim.getIncidentAcctSecFacts().add(iasFact);
                account.getIncidentAcctSecFacts().add(iasFact);
                incident.getIncidentAcctSecFacts().add(iasFact);

                if(!updatedStatus){ 
                    iaFact.setAccountDim(account);
                    iaFact.setIncidentDim(incident);
                    iaFact.setInsUsrC(loginUser);
                    iaFact.setInsTsD(AppGlobalUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp());
                    iaFact.setDelIndC(AppGlobalConstants.HardCodedValues.No);

                    incident.getIncidentAcctFacts().add(iaFact);
                    account.getIncidentAcctFacts().add(iaFact);
                }
                incident.setTotGainLossN(totalSecGL);

                cerSecurityDimDao.saveOrUpdate(cerSecDim);
                incidentAcctSecFactDao.saveOrUpdate(iasFact);
                if(!updatedStatus){
                    accountDimDao.saveOrUpdate(account);
                }
                if(!acctList.contains(account)){
                    acctList.add(account);
                }
                if(!cerSecList.contains(cerSecDim)){
                    cerSecList.add(cerSecDim);
                }
                if(!iasFactList.contains(iasFact)){
                    iasFactList.add(iasFact);
                }
                if(!updatedStatus){
                    incidentAcctFactDao.saveOrUpdate(iaFact);
                }
                incidentDimDao.saveOrUpdate(incident);

                NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
                incidentDetailsForm.setTotalGainLoss(formatter.format(totalSecGL));

                savedStatus = true;

                /*accountsList.add(account);
                cerSecuList.add(cerSecDim);
                inciAcctSecFactList.add(iasFact);
                inciAcctFactList.add(iaFact);
                incidentList.add(incident);*/
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        finally{
            baseViewBean$Session.getExcelRecords().clear();
            baseViewBean$Session.setExcelRecords(null);
        }

        /*accountDimDao.saveOrUpdateAll(accountsList);
        cerSecurityDimDao.saveOrUpdateAll(cerSecuList);
        incidentAcctSecFactDao.saveOrUpdateAll(inciAcctSecFactList);
        incidentAcctFactDao.saveOrUpdateAll(inciAcctFactList);
        incidentDimDao.saveOrUpdateAll(incidentList);*/

        return savedStatus;
    }

The dao functions are accessed from another file. 

Please let me know how i can increase my performance.
```

Comment: When you are inserting over 10K records there will always be some delay.. How big a delay are we talking about? Minutes?

Comment: What does the database report it is doing?

Comment: Did you profile your code? Is more time spent on saving data to the database or parsing data into Java Objects or what??

Comment: @Thihara - We are speaking about more than 2 hours for processing.

Comment: Are you doing straight up insertions?

Comment: @Thihara - My log shows it keeps retrieving the data.Nothing persisted yet.The log is as follows. Hibernate: select ACCOUNT_DIM_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select INCIDENT_ACCT_FACT_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate:select this_.PYCIS_INSTN_ID_N as y0_, this_.GDW_ID_N as y1_ from V_INVESTMENT_DIM this_ where lower(this_.AS400SHRTNM_C)=?
Hibernate:select this_.PYCIS_INSTN_ID_N as y0_, this_.GDW_ID_N as y1_ from V_INVESTMENT_DIM this_ where lower(this_.AS400SHRTNM_C)=?
Hibernate: /* criteria query */ select this_.SECU_DIM_ID_N as **** from V_SECURITY_DIM this_ where lower(this_.FMR_CUSIP_C)=?

Comment: cannot tell from what you posted what the scope of your hibernate session and transactions are.  If every DAO call is starting a new session, getting a new connection, starting a new transaction, that is very bad.  If the entire thing is all in one gigantic session and one gigantic transaction, that is also bad.  You have to group it into sane units of work.

Comment: The problem is we need to iterate to retrieve the data in the loop and i guess that is taking time. I can somehow overcome that by pulling out the required data even before processing. That way i can save some time, but can i do anything to fasten the processing?

Comment: @Affe - It is one gigantic session. How else can it be processed? How can i break into smaller units if work?

Comment: Simplest thing to do to start is flush and clear every 100 or so passes and see if that helps.  Also looks like there are some select statements in there.  L2 Cache and Query Cache may help with that.

Comment: I also tried to finish the relationships(setting the one to many relationship), add them to a list and then do saveOrUpdateAll(), but it gives me transient state, empty state exceptions. Failure on that end too.

Comment: alright then, i will try two things now. 1. try to avoid the hibernate call in the loop 2. flush and clear after every 100 inserts. i will post my updates after doing the necessary changes in about 2 hrs time. Meantime Thanks all for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Take a look at this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html. If you read through everything and apply it I'm sure you will see quite a bit of improvement. Also try to create the primary keys from the Java program. I've heard that from a colleague of mine though so not sure if that will help much....

Comment: i was able to somehow call the select outside the method, but when i run the following statements i get "not-null property references a null or transient value:".I am trying to save new Parent and Children at one. Cant i do the following cerSecurityDimDao.saveOrUpdateAll(cerSecuList);
accountDimDao.saveOrUpdateAll(accountsList);
incidentDimDao.saveOrUpdateAll(incidentList);

Comment: ok, i am thinking of running the entire set of queries from a stored procedure. Can anyone please let me know as to how i can get the relationships or pass on the relationships to a procedure to execute the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to do this from a browser, where the default timeout for a page is 30 seconds. You should be doing this from an application so that you can control the amount of time you wait to upload the records.

Comment: Ajax anyone???? As far as I know Ajax requests can be used to get around the timeout problem...

Comment: But i want to do this from a browser, cant i do anything to speed up the process.

Comment: yes, you can use ajax. That is a good way to start this process, but you have to upload all the data to the server from the client first, then you have to insert all the data. If you have to have this web based, have one method to start the insertion, and another to monitor the progress.

Answer (score 0):

I am having lookalike problems.

- Make sure that you have all keys for join and search fields.
- May be you can store your file in temporary location and then handle it by paralell thread.
- Another option is to use Stateless Sessions (there is almost no info on the net, see hibernate manual) I am not sure if there is an option to fill ManyToMany collections.
- Caching getOrCreate queries by saving copy of table in memory may help you (but you may run into OutOfMemory exception, so pass -Xmx param to your app).
- All these may not solve your problem. I've decided to implement these inserts using native sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues that should be looked at:

1. Long-running operations should be run asynchronously.  If you are using Spring, you can annotate `@Async`, for instance.  Then your transaction is not beholden to network connectivity or browser/HTTP timeouts.
2. Batch operations in Hibernate can be very slow.  Even if you set up JDBC batching, and even if you follow the instructions [in the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html), you are still beholden to the fact that you are using an ORM.  ORMS are best used for maintaining state for object-oriented operations, not for batch operations, where any individual object's state is less relevant.
3. Batch operations in Hibernate can be very finicky.  For instance, the Hibernate batching documentation fails to note that you need to set additional flags in the configuration to make sure that it batches correctly.  See [this post](http://abramsm.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/hibernate-batch-processing-why-you-may-not-be-using-it-even-if-you-think-you-are/) for details.

At the end of the day, ORMs will always be slower than base SQL.  Consider swtiching over to base SQL, maybe concatenating SQL statements so that you have fewer database trips, or using a stored proc, passing bactches of data to the proc and have it run the inserts.

Answer (score 0):

when you open session use openStatelessSession  and call session.update at the end. this way persistentcontext cannot have 10000 object in cache and all the updates happens in db.